# How is the specific object removed from the array inside the object? (with pop() or another solution)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to remove the 'hello5' from the years in myObj.

I used 'pop' prototype, but the browser console return this result :

*'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined'*

The following is an example for my issue. You could try and will see error message from console.

I tried a long time but I didn't find any solution, I need your advise and solution.

Code :

```
var myObj = {
  test : 'testObje',
  langs : {
    0 : 'EN',
    1 : 'GR',
    2 : 'RU',
    3 : 'TR'
  },
  comment : 'testComment'
};
var years = [];
  for (i= 0; i<=10; i++)
    {
      years.push({
        operator : i,
        type : 'hello' + i
      });
};
myObj.years = years;

var myObjLeng = myObj.years.length;
for(var i = 0; i < myObjLeng; i++) {
    if(myObj.years[i].type == 'hello5') {
        myObj.years.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: **slice()** it, don’t **pop()** it. **pop()** gets the last item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good alternatives here, so let me just take a stab at why you're getting that error.

You're getting that error because you're changing the length of the array mid-loop. At the beginning of the loop, you have 11 elements, and you use that to define how many times your `for` loop will go. When you get to `hello5`, you `pop` the last element off, making your array 10 elements long. However, your `for` loop will still try to access the 11th element. That will be `undefined`, and when you try to access a proprty of `undefined` (e.g. `type`), you will get a TypeError.

Comment: Yeah, there are good alternative here. Your comment is noticeable value to understanding error. It will help that  who don't understand to why this error. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

What about this one?

```
myObj.years = myObj.years.filter(year => year.type != "hello5")
```

in short you take `myObj.years` array an filter each of its elements called `year` in filiter callback. Filter will pass-thru these elements whose condition is met. All will met except ones with `type` with your`"hello5"` expression. Finally you substitute result back and you are done.

Comment: Thank you for  explanation and supporting :)

Answer (score 2):

`pop` always removes the last element, `pop` mutates original array, which affects index and you end up accessing indexs out of array length, you can simply use filter

```js
let myObj = {test: 'testObje',langs: {0: 'EN',1: 'GR',2: 'RU',3: 'TR'},comment: 'testComment'};

let years = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  years.push({ operator: i, type: 'hello' + i  });
};

myObj.years = years.filter(({type})=> type !== 'hello5')

console.log(myObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object key selection was wrong. Instead of for loop I suggest you to use `map()` function.

```js
var myObj = {
        test : 'testObje',
        langs : {
            0 : 'EN',
            1 : 'GR',
            2 : 'RU',
            3 : 'TR'
        },
        comment : 'testComment'
    };
    var years = [];
    for (i= 0; i<=10; i++)
    {
        years.push({
            operator : i,
            type : 'hello' + i
        });
    };
    
    myObj.years = years;

    myObj.years.map((item, key) => {
        Object.keys(item).map(i => myObj.years[key][i] === 'hello5' && (delete myObj.years[key]))
    })

    console.log(myObj)
```

Comment: I like to your solution. Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

pop will remove the last element, which will change the original array, that's why you are getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" because after pop the index you are trying to access is not found on the array, instead use "array.filter"

```
let myObj =
  {
    test: 'testObje',
    langs: {0: 'EN',1: 'GR',2: 'RU',3: 'TR'},comment: 'testComment'
  };

let years = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  years.push({ operator: i, type: 'hello' + i  });
};

myObj.years = years.filter(({type}) => type !== 'hello5')
```

Comment: Thank you for  explanation and supporting :)